# Converting OHLCV Intraday Data to Higher Timeframes

Tags: python, cryptocurrency, ohlcv

Just new to Python programming. So I have crypto OHLCV data on the four hour timeframe. I want to convert them to daily, weekly, and monthly data. The data is in a csv file. Here is a sample:

BTCUSDT 06/01/2021 , 08:00:00   37253.82     37894.81   36478        36704.99   14647.05841
BTCUSDT 06/01/2021 , 12:00:00   36706.8      37443.72   36561.89     36831.58   10095.34783
BTCUSDT 06/01/2021 , 16:00:00   36831.58     36939.81   35902.43     36596.62   13819.88776
BTCUSDT 06/01/2021 , 20:00:00   36596.63     37440      35666        36235.29   22029.82561
BTCUSDT 06/02/2021 , 00:00:00   36235.28     36492.89   35716.66     35973.87   12918.45296
BTCUSDT 06/02/2021 , 04:00:00   35973.86     36800      35873.08     36693.09    7724.091195
ETHUSDT 06/01/2021 , 08:00:00   2706.15      2740        2612.63      2630.79   190770.2435
ETHUSDT 06/01/2021 , 12:00:00   2630.66      2716.33     2615.27      2652.53   166661.3018
ETHUSDT 06/01/2021 , 16:00:00   2652.37      2672.6      2547.12      2624.09   263021.1097
ETHUSDT 06/01/2021 , 20:00:00   2624.23      2666        2523.74      2568.49   294840.3197
ETHUSDT 06/02/2021 , 00:00:00   2568.62      2588        2535.72      2634.57   125258.4908
BNBUSDT 06/01/2021 , 08:00:00   353.37       364.4        343.42       345.77   727379.1453
BNBUSDT 06/01/2021 , 12:00:00   345.74       360          343.74       349.06   599663.416
BNBUSDT 06/01/2021 , 16:00:00   349.14       357.21       339.48       353.79   802504.2916
BNBUSDT 06/01/2021 , 20:00:00   353.83       358.18       342          348.85   700365.912
BNBUSDT 06/02/2021 , 00:00:00   348.85       355.19       345.77       349.74   377847.017

(The order of the columns from left to right: symbol, opening time, open, high, low, close, volume)

Source of data is from the binance. I could have just opted to download the daily timeframe, etc but I can't because:

- it takes a lot of time to download data across different timeframes so I just opted to download
  lower timeframe and build higher timeframe data from them
- I frequently get errors when downloading from the binance api (bec I probably reached the max limit
  of requests) so I'm minimizing my downloads to just the lower timeframes
- lastly, when I download the daily, the opening data seems to start at 8:00:00 instead of at
  00:00:00. Probably because the timezone in my area is UTC + 8.

I have seen a few variations of my question asked online with the solutions given using the pandas library. But being a newbie, I have difficulty understanding them (stuff like the index) so I prefer  to not use libraries like pandas.

Comment: You will really need to understand some basics of Python and at least some very simple examples of Pandas. It is very difficult for a newbie to do this task (resample OHLCV and deal with datetimes) without the _help_ of Pandas. There is no better way to do this.
Please try to breakdown the problems one-by-one. Downloading from Binance via API / OHLCV candlestick resample / Timezone conversions are three different topics. Assuming you are really new to Python and the community, I am throwing some keywords hope it helps: `pd.read_csv()`, `pd.resample()`, `pd.to_datetime()`.

Comment: Hi Tyson. Thanks for the advice. May I ask if there is a way to "turn off the timezone conversion" in binance (not sure about the correct term so I don't know what to type in the google search bar) As I've said, in the daily, the opening is set at 8:00:00 and the closing is based on the next day at 7:59:59.  The weekly and monthly might also be the same. But in the intraday intervals, its fine. So when i look at the charts, it's confusing when I zoom in on the daily interval.

Comment: A convenient way to handle datetime info is to start with Timestamp - it is the number of seconds lapsed since 1970-01-01, so it is free from annoying timezone problems. eg. the current timestamp when I am typing this is 1650916916. From my experience this is commonly notated as field `t` in Binance API. Keywords on dealing with this is eg. pandas convert timestamp to datetime. Note that this is not a Binance-specific thing, it is common in practical programming.